How to use openapi-generator-cli with the typescript-angular generator
I'm trying to generate code from my swagger.json file but I'm getting rows of these errors where "operationId is repeated:
-attribute paths.'/operable-equipment/1.3/type/{type}'(get).operationId is repeated
I've tried using additional-properties like this, but not sure which variation of properties to use:
--additional-properties=propertyName=true"
I've tried a config file like this, but once again not sure which ones to use:
-c openapiconfig.json
{
    "ngVersion": "18.1.2",
    "supportsES6": "true",
    "withInterfaces": true
}

I saw a similar issue with the property name "repeated" where they use the validateSpec or skipValidateSpec but I don't see these properties from the typescript-angular generator.
